# Max storage limit(Size in GB) for Non-partitioned collections in Azure Cosmos DB Mongo DB

Tags: mongodb, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am planning to create an azure monitor alert when an **Azure cosmos db mongo db** collection is 75% full. I have created collection without partition-key and Fixed storage capacity(20 GB) using Azure portal. At-present Azure portal allows collections with unlimited storage capacity only if they have partition-key.

Though while trying to create "Available Storage" alert for collection It displayed warning that "Available Storage" alert is deprecated and after checking Azure documentation I found following statement.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/metrics-supported

"Available Storage" will be removed from Azure Monitor at the end of September 2020. Cosmos DB collection storage size is now unlimited. The only restriction is that the storage size for each logical partition key is 20GB. You can enable PartitionKeyStatistics in Diagnostic Log to know the storage consumption for top partition keys. For more info about Cosmos DB storage quota, please check this doc https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/concepts-limits. After deprecation, the remaining alert rules still defined on the deprecated metric will be automatically disabled post the deprecation date.

Will Available storage for collection autoscale and dynamically increase after consumed storage is increased?
Is there any limit on storage per collection(for collections with no partition-key) on Azure cosmos db for mongo db?

If collection can have max 20 GB(Fixed) storage then if I create azure monitor alert for 25% "Available Storage" will it work?

Comment: Welcome! I would suggest reading up on Cosmos DB's limits, especially around partitions. tl;dr you cannot increase a partition's size beyond the maximum physical partition allowed. So no, there can be no auto-scaling if you have a fixed (non-partitioned) collection.

Comment: Thank you @DavidMakogon, Can we create Azure monitor alert to raise an alert for a collection with Fixed storage capacity(20 GB) , I tried using "Available Storage (deprecated)" alert but looks like its not per collection, because I have not received any alert even after collection storage has crossed alert condition.

Is "Available Storage" correct alert to create alert for a non-partitioned Fixed storage collection? Or something else I need to do to get storage alert for non-partitioned Fixed storage collection in Cosmos DB for Mongo DB API.